# Create a Value/Constant from a value by reference, and then what's the difference?

Tags: swift, reference

I kind of know what is by reference and by value in general, but for some points I feel very confused with details

Let's define the class `Person` and initialize a **Constant** and a **Variable** from it and then pass them around the code

```
class Person{
    var ID: Int
    var name: String

    init (ID: Int, name: String){
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name 
    }
}

var bornVar = Person(ID: 101, name: "me")  //  initialize a variable
let Tom = bornVar // pass the varialbe to a constant
var Tim = Tom // pass the variable to a variable 


let bornLet = Person(ID: 102, name: "I") //  initialize a constant
let Kim = bornLet // pass the constant to another constant
var Jim = Kim  // pass the constant to a variable
```

**Question**: If someone ask me: what is the difference between `Tom`, `Tim`, `Kim` and `Jim`, I can't give out a clear answer. Very appreciate if someone can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bornVar = Person(ID: 101, name: "me")  //  initialize a variable
let Tom = bornVar // assigning the ref of `bornVar` which is having person object reference and you can't assign the any other object to `Tom`
var Tim = Tom // assigning the reference of person object using `Tom` 


let bornLet = Person(ID: 102, name: "I") //  initialize a constant
let Kim = bornLet // pass the constant to another constant
var Jim = Kim  // pass the constant to a variable
```

You created here two objects  `bornVar` and `bornLet` with parameterzied init which are pointing to Person

`Tom` is a property which reference we can't change and it is pointing to `bornVar` which is a having person object reference

`Tim` is a property which is pointing to `bornVar` and you can change it reference

**in the same way**

`Kim` is a property which reference we can't change and it is pointing to `bornLet` which is a having person object reference

`Jim` is a property which is pointing to `bornLet` and you can change it reference

look at this example

```
class MyObject : Equatable {
let a : Int, b : String
init(a: Int, b: String) { self.a = a; self.b = b }
}
// ...

let a = MyObject(a: 10, b: "foo")
let b = a
let c = MyObject(a: 10, b: "foo")

a == b    // true; 'a' and 'b' are equal in value
a === b   // true; 'a' and 'b' point to the same instance

a == c    // true; 'a' and 'b' are equal in value
a === c   // false; 'a' and 'c' are different instances
```

Comment: I think I know the concept better now, Which means I cannot assign Kim to Tom ( Tom = Kim // wrong) but assigning Kim to Tim is OK (Tim = Kim // valid)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and very detialed example